# GitHub Actions reusable workflow cannot parse the matrix when calling another reusable workflow using matrix strategy

Tags: github-actions

I'm using 2-level nested re-usable workflows, so the main workflow M calls workflow A that calls another workflow B. M runs a job that forms a JSON that's passed as a string to A. A then has two jobs: first, JOB1, calls B with matrix strategy, reading matrix with fromJson; second, JOB2, has some explicit steps defined, also with matrix strategy from the exact same matrix. JOB2 needs JOB1.
Now the funny thing is, as soon as I introduce JOB1 into the workflow A, it fails claiming it can't render the strategy (specific details ommitted):

```
Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'JOB1'. path-to-yml (Line: X, Col: Y): Error parsing fromJson,path-to-yml (Line: X, Col: Y): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,path-to-yml (Line: X, Col: Y): Unexpected type of value '', expected type: Mapping.
```

So from the error message it seems that the matrix string is empty and can't be parsed. However the debug output (just echoing the string) in a separate job shows it's a perfectly valid JSON. As soon as I comment out JOB1, JOB2 runs perfectly with literally no other changes. If I change the aforementioned debug job to also use the matrix strategy and make it needed for JOB2, everything runs once again. If I call workflow B directly from workflow M, it also works.

Here's a reproducible example:

main.yml:

```
name: main workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:
  matrix-gen:
    name: generate matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output-matrix: ${{ steps.generate.outputs.output-matrix }}
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo -n "::set-output name=output-matrix::{\"include\": [{\"key\": \"value1\"}, {\"key\": \"value2\"}]}"
        id: generate

  debug-output-main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - matrix-gen
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo ${{ needs.matrix-gen.outputs.output-matrix }}

  call-A:
    needs:
      - matrix-gen
    uses: ./.github/workflows/A.yml
    with:
      matrix-input: ${{ needs.matrix-gen.outputs.output-matrix }}

  call-B-from-main:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/B.yml
    needs:
      - matrix-gen
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.matrix-gen.outputs.output-matrix) }}
    with:
      value: ${{ matrix.key }}
```

A.yml:

```
name: reusable workflow A
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      matrix-input:
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  debug-output-A:
    name: debug output
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(inputs.matrix-input) }}
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo '${{ matrix.key }}'

  call-B-plain:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/B.yml
    with:
      value: 'arbitrary string'

  call-B-with-matrix:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/B.yml
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(inputs.matrix-input) }}
    with:
      value: ${{ matrix.key }}
```

B.yml:

```
name: reusable workflow B
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      value:
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  debug-output-B:
    name: debug output
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo '${{ inputs.value }}'
```

In this example, literally everything works, except `call-B-with-matrix` which fails to render the strategy with the aforementioned error message. Since there's a job `debug-output-A` a couple of lines above, that uses the exact same string to derive the strategy, I cannot see what's changing between those two calls. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in GitHub Actions implementation, it's been reported by me and fixed since I filed the ticket. Cannot share the link here as it's not publicly accessible report anyway, and I've lost the account that was used to file it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with a similar use case in my workflow. My suspicion is that there is a bug pertaining to how GitHub Actions interprets whitespace in the `run` section. Ironically, I added `set -x` to the top of my step that generated the matrix, and suddenly it started working.

Have you filed a bug on GitHub? If so, I'd like to follow it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me about this! I actually have filed a ticket, and it was patched a couple of months ago. I'm away from computer right now, but IIRC it was due some internal variable re-initialisation, so one couldn't use matrix of matrices, if that makes sense. I'll be able to tell for sure in a week. If you ran into your bug a while ago, maybe it was also fixed?

Comment: It is possible that the bug I'm experiencing has been fixed - I've been running against an instance GitHub Enterprise that's a couple minor versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a HereDoc style when creating the matrix
eg

```bash
- name: Generate Matrix
   id: generate-matrix
   run: |
     echo "For the matrix step later we need to create the output via a here doc method"
     echo "output-matrix<<EOF" >> ${GITHUB_OUTPUT}
     echo -n "{\"include\": [{\"key\": \"value1\"}, {\"key\": \"value2\"}]}" >> ${GITHUB_OUTPUT}
     echo "EOF" >> ${GITHUB_OUTPUT}
```

You can add some uniqueness with `DELIMITER="$(openssl rand -hex 8)"` and `${DELIMITER}` instead of `EOF`

Can you also use `jq` or whatever else to build the json doc and write it to a file instead of inline, then `cat myfile.json >> ${GITHUB_OUTPUT}`

Comment: If you mean that you should re-generate the matrix to pass it further, I guess that could work, but the behaviour described is a bug that's been fixed, and one should not be working around it.

Comment: No I was saying that you need to have some other delimiter rather than a simple new line. It it was fixed within the 10 days between me posting and your response then great.
The issue was still present when I posted my response

In essence a github workflow is a yaml document and part way through that yaml doc someone wants to create an anchor to be used elsewhere

Comment: I was having a different issue. The matrix is generated perfectly well and is readable by one workflow, and then lost for the other.